# Stacking Multiple Ternary Operators in PHP

Tags: php, operators, ternary-operator

This is what I wrote :

```
 $Myprovince = (
($province == 6) ? "city-1" :
($province == 7) ? "city-2" :
($province == 8) ? "city-3" :
($province == 30) ? "city-4" : "out of borders"
);
```

But for every field I got the value `city-4`.  I want to use ternary operators instead of `switch/if` because I want to experiment and see how it would be done.

What's the problem with this code?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just use `if / elseif` or `switch` ?

Comment: You'd need many more brackets for this to work. User a `switch` as Marc suggested.

Comment: @Mac: you're driving me crazy with curiosity :D !  Why do you need to use ternary operators?

Comment: Using ternary operators with complex nested conditions is __not recommended__ for very good reasons... because they're fraught with problems, and it's extremely difficult to identify bugs. You've just discovered this! If you really knew how to use them, you wouldn't be asking for help! So why do you still want to use ternary operators in this case?

Comment: im using ternary operators because of my own curiosity nothing else , i know its not good for complex conditions statement but in learning and testing php details i need to correct it :D

Comment: Check your answers below:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235632/5235721#5235721

Comment: Wow, this is the most heavily voted-on bunch of comments and answers I've ever seen.

Comment: @Jonah: You must be new here.

Comment: @Mac at least tell us you're not using this in real code so we can feel better about it

Comment: god , please , I WOULD NOT USE THIS Method in a live script , never ever , are you better now ? just curious how to use it :D

Comment: wow. If there's a legitimate reason the code is not working as expected, then by all means point it out. "answers" questioning the motives of arbitrary examples are far more inappropriate than the motive of arbitrary examples. +1 to codaddict and @arnorhs for thoughtful additions.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Others have already suggested the right way of doing it but if you really want to use ternary operator you need to use parenthesis as:

```
$province = 7;
 $Myprovince = (
 ($province == 6) ? "city-1" :
  (($province == 7) ? "city-2" :
   (($province == 8) ? "city-3" :
    (($province == 30) ? "city-4" : "out of borders")))
 );
```

[Updated Link](http://deadlytechnology.com/web-development-tips/php-ternary-syntax/)

Comment: *shudder* I'd +1 your bravery for typing that out, but can't bring myself to "endorse" such a hideous thing...

Comment: This is indeed the "correct" way to do it. I would never ever attempt anything like this though.

Comment: +1 Correct (yet horrifying). Still, you were just satisfying the OPs freakish whim to do the wrong thing. (Nothing to see here, move along please.) :-)

Comment: thanks man this is what i looking for .. i don't even know why they trying to suggest other ways !

Comment: @Mac If you *really* think this is the best solution (despite the disclaimer made by @codeaddict), then all I can hope is that I never have to maintain any of your code in the future. A `switch` statement or array lookup is the sane way to go if you care about code legibility/maintainability.

Comment: They suggested other ways because you never said you wanted this done via `ternary` in your original post.

Comment: I said so . but a bad mistake happened , i created two topics mistakenly , and in that topic i said that "don't suggest other ways"... and lovely to see that , the topic is getting more and more negative points .

Comment: @Mac Taylor: You are using the wrong tool for the job. There is nothing more to say about it. You could also create the string `'abc'` with string concatenation `'a'.'b'.'c'`, but why doing so? Have fun adding a new city to your ternary beast and don't forget to count to match the parenthesis!

Comment: @Mac Taylor: For more information, have a look at the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: I'm wonder, is there a documented reason for the author's code to not work? From what I know it looks to me like a PHP bug.

Comment: I think it is not a good response to reject the use of chained ternary as a programming pattern. It makes for concise clear code in the numerous languages that implement it "properly" and because it generates **an expression**, sometimes it is the only way to quickfix something. I used quotes because while the PHP designers did make the asinine choice to make its ternary operator left-associative, the fact is well-documented.

Answer (score 38):

The ternary operator is evaluated from left to right. So if you don't group the expressions properly, you will get an unexpected result.

[PHP's advice is <sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

> It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious.

Your code actually is evaluated as:

```
(
    (
        (
            $province == 6 ? "city-1" : $province == 7
        ) ? "city-2" : 
        $province == 8
    ) ? "city-3" : $province == 30
) ? "city-4" : "out of borders";
```

where it should be

```
$province == 6 ? "city-1" : (
    $province == 7 ? "city-2" : (
        $province == 8 ? "city-3" : (
           $province == 30 ? "city-4" : "out of borders"
        )
    )
);
```

This code might look fine but someone will read it and they will need more time than they should to understand what this code is doing.

---

You would be better off with something like this:

```
$map = array( 6 = >'city-1', 
              7 => 'city-2', 
              8 => 'city-3', 
             30 => 'city-4');

$Myprovince = "out of borders";

if(array_key_exists($province, $map)) {
    $Myprovince = $map[$province];
}
```

Or as [@Jonah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/278899/jonah) mentioned in his comment:

```
$Myprovince = isset($map[$province]) ? $map[$province] : 'out of borders';
```

Comment: Make it even shorter with this: `$Myprovince = isset($map[$province]) ? $map[$province] : 'out of borders';` ;-)

Comment: @Jonah: True :D I guess I wanted to go away from the ternary operator as far as possible ;)

Comment: To your edit, I believe that the other lines are the c statements for the previous lines.  Notice, no semi-colons.  It's pretty much just: `($province == 6) ? "city-1" : ($province == 7) ? "city-2" : ($province == 8) ? "city-3" : ($province == 30) ? "city-4" : "out of borders";`

Comment: @Phoenix: Yeah I noticed it and fixed it. I got very confused by all this `?` and `:` ;)

Comment: PHP's the only language of the ternary operator capable languages, that works differently from other languages' implementation:

http://phpsadness.com/sad/30

Comment: definitely the best solution to this problem

Comment: or `$Myprovince = $map[$province] ??  'out of borders';`

Comment: Note that PHP 8 has disabled nested ternaries without explicit parentheses.

Answer (score 19):

Don't abuse the ternary operator for that sort of thing. It makes debugging near impossible to follow. Why not do something like

```
switch($province) {
    case 6: $Myprovince = "city-1"; break;
    case 7: ...
}
```

or simply some chained if/then/else

```
if ($province == 6) {
     $Myprovince = "city-1";
} elseif ($province = ...) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: didn't i mentioned that i insist in using tenary operators because some reasons ?

Comment: @Mac Taylor: No you didn't. What is the reason? Obscurity?

Comment: @Felix: perhaps debugging masochism?

Comment: The big benefit of the ternary over these is that it allows having a single variable assignment.

Comment: AND DO NOT FOREGET, *switch - case* is always  faster  that *if - else* branched !

Answer (score 15):

Some people have suggested using a switch statement or an if/else statement. But I would use an array instead, to make it easier to maintain and easier to read:

```
$provinces = array (
    6 => 'city-1',
    7 => 'city-2',
    8 => 'city-3',
    30 => 'city-4'
);

// then you can call:

$Myprovince = isset($provinces[$province]) ? $provinces[$province] : 'out of borders';
```

### Why?

The code will probably eventually be easier to manage. Maybe you'll want to add those province-to-city mappings from database one day.. etc.. That will be hard to maintain with a bunch of switch/case statements.

Comment: I would do like you. Definitely the best answer!

Comment: This one is good. Be careful of "out of memory" problem though.

Answer (score 7):

I understand this is a question about PHP, but since this is just an educational exercise anyways I thought you might be interested in learning that Ruby and Javascript actually behave the way you expect.

Ruby:

```
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :009 > def foo x
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :010?>   x == 1 ? "city 1" : x == 2 ? "city 2" : "out of borders"
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :011?>   end
 => nil
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :012 > foo 1
 => "city 1"
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :013 > foo 2
 => "city 2"
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :014 > foo 3
 => "out of borders"
```

Javascript:

```
> function f(x) { return x == 1 ? "city 1" : x == 2 ? "city 2" : "out of borders"; }
undefined
> f(1)
"city 1"
> f(2)
"city 2"
> f(3)
"out of borders"
```

Comment: *shrug* ... of course Ruby and Javascript already do it ... they are programming languages after all ^_^

Answer (score 4):

I think the more readable way to write nested ternary operators in PHP is like this:

```
$myprovince =
    $province ==  6 ? "city-1" : (
    $province ==  7 ? "city-2" : (
    $province ==  8 ? "city-3" : (
    $province == 30 ? "city-4" : "out of borders" )));
```

All you need to do is count the number of opening parenthesis (`(`) and add the same number of closing parenthesis (`)`) at the end of the last line.

Another option is to use one-line if/elseif/else, as already suggested - however, I would format them visually like this for even more readability:

```
if      ($province == 6)  $myprovince = "city-1";
elseif  ($province == 7)  $myprovince = "city-2";
elseif  ($province == 8)  $myprovince = "city-3";
elseif  ($province == 30) $myprovince = "city-4";
else                      $myprovince = "out of borders";
```

Answer (score 4):

The best and most readable (IMO) solution for this was introduced with [the `match` statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php) in PHP 8:

```php
$Myprovince = match ($province) {
    6       => "city-1",
    7       => "city-2",
    8       => "city-3",
    30      => "city-4",
    default => "out of borders",
};
```

It's essentially just a less-verbose `switch` statement that's ideal for simple assignment. Multiple conditions can be added as well:

```php
$Myprovince = match ($province) {
    4, 5, 6  => "city-1",
    7, 9, 10 => "city-2",
    8        => "city-3",
    30       => "city-4",
    default  => "out of borders",
};
```

Comment: I was *just* wondering if there existed some PHP equivalent of Java's *switch expression*. Well, here it is.

Answer (score 3):

Try with some more parenthesis :

```
$Myprovince = (
($province == 6) ? "city-1" :
(($province == 7) ? "city-2" :
(($province == 8) ? "city-3" :
(($province == 30) ? "city-4" : "out of borders"
))));
```

Your code has a problem with the ternary operator priority.

But I think you should really drop this operator and try to use a `switch` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I got myself into the same problem today. The others already giving acceptable solutions. Mine just an emphasis to one liner ifs. More readable in my opinion.

```
if ($province == 6) $Myprovince = 'city-1';
elseif ($province == 7) $Myprovince = 'city-2';
elseif ($province == 8) $Myprovince = 'city-3';
elseif ($province == 30) $Myprovince = 'city-4';
else $Myprovince = 'out of borders';
```

Comment: Switches are ugly, yes, but better would be a lookup array with a `isset()` check -- easy and clean.

Answer (score 2):

In this type of case I always recommend to use switch case syntax. As you said it's experimental so here is the code you need to use:

```
$province = 9;
$Myprovince = $province == 6 ? "city-1" : (
    $province == 7 ? "city-2" : (
        $province == 8 ? "city-3" : (
            $province == 9 ? "city-4" : "out of border"
        )
    )
);
echo $Myprovince;
```

The output will be:

```
out of border because the $province is = 9
```

Again I recommend to use switch case. Below the code:

```
switch ($province) {
    case 6:
        $Myprovince = 'city-1';
        break;
    case 7:
        $Myprovince = 'city-2';
        break;
    case 8:
        $Myprovince = 'city-3';
        break;
    case 9:
        $Myprovince = 'city-4';
        break;
    default:
        $Myprovince = 'out of borders';
}
```

There is some other **Ternary Operators** that we can use in PHP

**The shorthand ternary operator**

```
$result = $initial ?: 'default';
```

In this case, the value of **$result** will be the value of **$initial**, unless **$initial** evaluates to false, in which case the string **'default'** is used.

**Chaining Ternary Operators**

We already used this type of ternary operators in our above code.

**Null Coalescing Operator**

t similar to the ternary operator, but will behave like isset on the lefthand operand instead of just using its boolean value. This makes this operator especially useful for arrays and assigning defaults when a variable is not set.

```
$undefined ?? 'fallback'; // 'fallback'
```

Because of $underfined variable the output will be fallback

```
$assigned = 'foo';
$assigned ?? 'fallback'; // 'foo'
```

The $assigned has a value now so the output will be "foo"

**Another Great Example**

You can use something like below in PHP.

```
$output = $truthy && 'The output here';
echo $output; // The output here
```

Please note the **&&**

Answer (score 1):

Use switch instead.  Ternary operators really shouldn't be used for more than single conditions, as they quickly become very difficult to understand.

```
switch ($province) {
    case 6:
        $Myprovince = 'city-1';
        break;
    case 7:
        $Myprovince = 'city-2';
        break;
    case 8:
        $Myprovince = 'city-3';
        break;
    case 30:
        $Myprovince = 'city-4';
        break;
    default:
        $Myprovince = 'out of borders';
}
```