# Nested ternery operators output wierd result

Tags: php, operator-keyword, ternary

This outputs 'Option 1'. I have no idea what is wrong with it.

```
$result = (0 == 0) ? 'Option 0' : (1==2) ? 'Option 1' : 'Option 2';
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sure this is documented behaviour.

Comment: Not only documented, but there is also [a note about using multiple of those](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison#language.operators.comparison.ternary). Possible Duplicate of [Stacking Multiple Ternary Operators in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5235632/367456)

Comment: `(Use parentheses for such situations.)` It helps with readability too. Stop spewing operators all over the place without wrapping them hence ensuring the are readable and that they act as you expect them to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an issue with [*Operator Precedence*](http://php.net/language.operators.precedence) and the [*Ternary Operator*](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison#language.operators.comparison.ternary) here. Your lack of understanding becomes visible where you place the parenthesis. Let's review:

```
$result = (0 == 0) ? 'Option 0' : (1 == 2) ? 'Option 1' : 'Option 2';
          ^      ^                ^     ^
```

I'm not saying it is easy, but as this code already shows, you have placed *superfluous* round brackets here. They are just not needed, this is often a sign of uncertainty with the own code. The correct variant would be:

```
$result = 0 == 0 ? 'Option 0' : 1 == 2 ? 'Option 1' : 'Option 2';
```

Now, this already shows that you are uncertain about where to place the parentheses. Knowing about this, also contains the solution to your problem. Turn your weakness into a strength by just doing the first check first and the second, second - but this time making actual use of parenthesis:

```
$result = 0 == 0 ? 'Option 0' : (1 == 2 ? 'Option 1' : 'Option 2');
                                ^                                ^
```

This will give you your expected result, the parenthesis control precedence now as intended.

---

*Tip:* You can make the [*decision tree*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) more visible by using indentation when you write such statements:

```
$result = 
    0 == 0 ? 'Option 0' 
           : (1 == 2 ? 'Option 1' 
                     : 'Option 2')
;
```

(or similar) Just to make this more readable at first glance. As it shows this *is* a complex decision. As with complex things, errors in writing code for them occur more often. That is normal. Keeping the code readable by using indentation can help. Another way is to reduce the complexity.

```
$decide  = 2:
$results = array(
    0 => 'Option 0', 
    1 => 'Option 1',
);
$result  = isset($results[$decide]) ? $results[$decide] : 'Default Option';
```

Here only one decision is needed, so it is less complex. This example makes more sense if you have more than three possibilities but even for three possibilities this can already be an improvement because it is visible right ahead that there is a default case.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a second set of grouping parens:

```
$result = (0 == 0) ? 'Option 0' : ((1==2) ? 'Option 1' : 'Option 2');
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, never tought of that :S

Answer (score 1):

You have to group the second path in quotes:

```
  $result = (0 == 0)?'Option 0':((1==2)?'Option 1':'Option 2');
```

BTW: Nesting / Stacking ternary is not recommended due to this unexpected behavior.  See the php documentation http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

> Note: It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious:

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$result = (0 == 0)? 'Option 0':((1==2) ? 'Option 1' : 'Option 2');
```

Output:

`Option 0`

Answer (score 1):

It's to do with it being right-associative (can't find source right now) - the right hand side is evaluated first. So, this part is evaluated first:

```
? 'Option 1' : 'Option 2';
```