# Laravel 5.2 conditional extends template in Blade

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to extend template based on condition. I know i can use `@if @else` statement in blade. I am doing the same thing, but blade extending both the template. I don't know why.

```
@if(isset(Auth::user()->id))
    @extends('layouts.adminlayout')
@else
   @extends('layouts.default')
@endif

@section('content')
    i am the home page
    {{ isset(Auth::user()->id) }}
@stop
```

As, you can see i am checking whether or not user login-ed and then extend the template layout. But it is extending from both the layout.

Please help me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first line in your extended blade view must be the `@extends` directive.
Try using a ternary operator for this.

```
@extends(isset(Auth::user()->id) ? 'layouts.adminlayout' : 'layouts.default');
```

UPDATE for role based layouts. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235632/stacking-multiple-ternary-operators-in-php) question for more conditions.

```
@extends((!isset(Auth::user()->id))? 'layouts.default': ((Auth::user()->role == 'admin') ? 'layouts.adminlayout' : 'layouts.moderatorlayout'));
```

Comment: that's cool, what about is i have multiple condition like authenticated user based on role and why my condition not working.

Comment: You can check users role on that condition.

Comment: could you please write that condition for admin and manager if user authenticated else default as i am not good with ternary operator.

Comment: Let me try. If not possible i'll get back to you. Now i am accepting your question. But my one question still remaining, why my condition not work ?

Comment: It's because The first line in your extended blade view must be the @extends directive

Comment: is it possible to pass in variables to be included with the `@extend` call in this case when using a ternary statement?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, parenterais are important

```
@extends(Auth::user()->rol_id == 1 ? 'layouts.admin' : ((Auth::user()->rol_id == 2) ? 'layouts.client' : 'layouts.client'))
```