# Shorthand IF inside an IF

Tags: php, html

Trying to find if a value is blank or has a value at all. If blank place a simple `<li>` element if there is a value does it equal the `$_GET` query. My return currently is blank. I am seeking a Ternary that has a true and false output without multiple iterative statements.

```
<?php 
    $res = "<li>";
    $tmp = "";
    if(isset($_GET['search-by'])){
        $tmp = $_GET['search-by'];
    }
?>

<ul>
   <?php ($tmp != "") ? (($tmp == "fullname") ? "<li class='actBL" : "<li>") : "<li>" ?>
    <a href="?search-by=fullname"> Name</a>
    </li>
    <?php ($tmp != "") ? (($tmp == "number") ? "<li class='actBL" : "<li>") : "<li>" ?>
    <a href="?search-by=number">Number</a>
    </li>
    <?php ($tmp != "") ? (($tmp == "dep") ? "<li class='actBL" : "<li>") : "<li>" ?>
    <a href="?search-by=dep">Department</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are never telling PHP to put it in the response (with `<?= ?>` or `echo` ) so it's not doing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stacking Multiple Ternary Operators in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235632/stacking-multiple-ternary-operators-in-php)

Comment: Yah I just noticed that

Comment: I looked up nested shorthand, and found my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just change the PHP open tag to the shortcut for `echo`.

```
<ul>
    <?= ($tmp != "") ? (($tmp == "fullname") ? "<li class='actBL'" : "<li>") : "<li>" ?>
    <a href="?search-by=fullname"> Name</a>
    </li>
    <?= ($tmp != "") ? (($tmp == "number") ? "<li class='actBL'" : "<li>") : "<li>" ?>
    <a href="?search-by=number">Number</a>
    </li>
    <?= ($tmp != "") ? (($tmp == "dep") ? "<li class='actBL'" : "<li>") : "<li>" ?>
    <a href="?search-by=dep">Department</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks yours worked perfectly.. I forgot to close the <li class='actBL can you do so in case others use your solution, it was my bad. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, you can just as well use a single ternary instead of chaining multiple ternary operators, but with both conditions, like this

```
!empty($tmp) && $tmp == "fullname" ? "<li class='actBL'>" : "<li>"
```

You're also not actually doing anything with it, you need to `echo` or use `<?=` instead of `<?php`. And you forgot to close off the `<li class=...>` tag. I've added `empty()` instead of comparing to empty string.

The final PHP should look something like this

```
<?php echo !empty($tmp) && $tmp == "fullname" ? "<li class='actBL'>" : "<li>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <li <?= (!empty($tmp) && $tmp == "fullname") ? " class='actBl'" : "" ?>>
    <a href="?search-by=fullname"> Name</a>
  </li>
  <li <?= (!empty($tmp) && $tmp == "number") ? " class='actBl'" : "" ?>>
    <a href="?search-by=number"> Number</a>
  </li>
  <li <?= (!empty($tmp) && $tmp == "dep") ? " class='actBl'" : "" ?>>
    <a href="?search-by=dep"> Department</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```