# Ternary ignores first condition

Tags: php, ternary-operator

Why is my ternary ignoring the first condition `($order->status === "prepairing")` ?

It always skips the first condition when checking the order status and immediately goes toward the second (and always see's it as true)

```
$messageMiddle = (  ($order->status === "prepairing") ? " your prder is being prepared. Make your way towards the store." 
                  : ($order->status === "complete")   ?' your order is done! Please show your order-code at the store.' 
                  : ' thank you for ordering ');
```

Comment: Perhaps a misspelling? "preparing" instead of "prepairing"?

Comment: Use braces to avoid unexpected behavior.

Comment: Don't stack ternary operations. Per the manual `It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious`

Comment: What have you done so far to debug the issue?

Comment: Try using just `==` instead of `===` in your tests. Unless you are 100% sure `$order->status` is a string the strict comparison may be failing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235632/stacking-multiple-ternary-operators-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group every next expression in parenthesis as follows. You forgot to enclose the second ternary expression in parentheses.

```
$messageMiddle = ($order->status === "prepairing") ? " your order is being prepared. Make your way towards the store." : 
                 (($order->status === "complete")  ? ' your order is done! Please show your order-code at the store.'  : ' thank you for ordering ');
```

But you should avoid this approach anyways.

Comment: Why should I avoid it?

Comment: Just because it brings in more complexity and prone to misunderstanding. Php.net self recommends to avoid stacking ternary operators. Here take a look https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Answer (score 1):

A better way to react to the status of an order would be a [switch statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php). Like this:

```
switch ($order->status) {
    case "preparing" : $messageMiddle = " your order is being prepared. Make your way towards the store.";
                       break;
    case "complete"  : $messageMiddle = " your order is done! Please show your order-code at the store.";
                       break;
    default          : $messageMiddle = " thank you for ordering ";
                       break;
}
```

It is easy to see how you can extend this to react to other status words.

Note that I changed `"prepairing" to "preparing".

One of the things programmers strive for is succinct code. However, shorter code is not always better code. It might be less readable and more difficult to maintain and extend.