# If elseif else ternary operator

Tags: php, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

How can I write this code as ternary operator:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {
$_SESSION['lang']   = $_SESSION['lang'];
} elseif (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
$_SESSION['lang']   = $_GET['lang'];
} else {
$_SESSION['lang']   = $defaultLanguage;
}
```

I used this code, but it does not work.

```
$lang   = (isset($_SESSION['lang']) ? $_SESSION['lang']) : (isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : $defaultLanguage);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure about the purpose of `$_SESSION['lang']   = $_SESSION['lang'];`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stacking Multiple Ternary Operators in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235632/stacking-multiple-ternary-operators-in-php). In particular, see the note about using multiple ternary operators in one statement. Generally a bad idea.

Comment: In particular I'd say see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5235687/3783243. The quote there is from PHP, not an SO user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use null coallescing (`??`)...

```
$lang = $_SESSION['lang'] ?? $_GET['lang'] ?? $defaultLanguage;
```