# Ternary stacking in php

Tags: php, ternary

What is the logic behind that the result is 'F' ?

```php
echo true ? 'T': false ? 'F':'D';
```

If i use parentheses it's ok, as new php versions want.
If it starts with the first ternary which is true, it should result 'T'.
If it starts with second ternary, which is false, should result 'D'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stacking Multiple Ternary Operators in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235632/stacking-multiple-ternary-operators-in-php)

Comment: Modern versions of php will start barfing when you fail to encapsulate ternary logic parenthetically.   https://3v4l.org/6pnDv  Ultimately, you should avoid writing nested ternaries because they negatively impact the readability of your script.

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by @Cray is a good thread - check especially [@Felix Kling answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5235687/4902724) and link to [PHP notes on ternary operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

To explain the logic - the ternary operator is evaluated from left to right - which in your case means:

- firstly, this part `true ? 'T': false` will result in: `'T'` (so you can replace this in the original expression)
- then you get: `'T' ? 'F':'D';` which will result in `'F'`