# Fatal error: Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is not supported. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)`

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this problem in a Theme of Wordpress. The problem is the line 298 in the extras.php

```
$author_name = ( trim( $author_nickname ) != "" ) ? $author_nickname : ( trim( $author_displayname ) != "" ) ? $author_displayname : $author_fullname ?>
```

I'm new on Wordpress, StackOverflow and I can't English 100% correctly. I wait you can help me :).

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Add some parenthesis in this formula.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stacking Multiple Ternary Operators in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235632/stacking-multiple-ternary-operators-in-php)