# PHP Error:Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is not supported. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)

Tags: php, admin

Hi I'm stuck on this error message. I tried to encapsulate it with parenthesis still I got an error on this specific line.

```
$section = false === $section ? $fields['checkout'] : isset( $fields[ $section ] ) ? $fields[ $section ] : [];

        return apply_filters( 'erp_ac_settings_section_fields_' . $this->id, $section );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stacking Multiple Ternary Operators in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235632/stacking-multiple-ternary-operators-in-php)

Comment: *"I tried to encapsulate it with parenthesis"* - Not in the code shown you didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You want one of the following depending on the logic, however an `if` would be much more readable and easier to debug:

```
           /* here                                                        to here */
$section = ( false === $section ? $fields['checkout'] : isset($fields[ $section ]) ) ? $fields[ $section ] : [];

//or
                                                      /* here                                         to here */    
$section = false === $section ? $fields['checkout'] : ( isset( $fields[ $section ]) ? $fields[ $section ] : [] );
```

Comment: AbraCadaver, Thanks man it solves my problem.

Comment: Please mark accepted if it solved your issue.