# Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is not supported. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)

Tags: php, php-8

i got this after upgrade tp php8 please help

Fatal error: Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is not supported. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)` in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/di-aiosc/class/class.ticket.php on line 35

the code is

```
$this->data->awaiting_reply = ($this->data->status == 'closed') ? false : ($this->data->status == 'queue') ? true : aiosc_enumToBool($this->data->awaiting_reply);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stacking Multiple Ternary Operators in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235632/stacking-multiple-ternary-operators-in-php)

Comment: As the error message says, you need to add parentheses to make clear what logic you intended. Note that it's quite likely that the code was subtly broken in older versions of PHP.