# How to write a PHP ternary statement with multiple conditions?

Tags: php

I'm trying to turn the following if/else statement into a ternary statement, but I'm not doing something right. I'm unsure where I'm going wrong.

**Original:**

```
<div class="banner <?php if($pencilbanner == 'hol') echo 'banner__holiday' ; else if($pencilbanner == 'std') echo 'banner__standard' ; else if($pencilbanner == 'lim') echo 'banner__limited' ; else 'banner__none'?>"></div>
```

**My Attempt:** (based on this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235632/stacking-multiple-ternary-operators-in-php))

```
<div class="banner <?php (($pencilbanner == 'hol') ? 'banner__holiday' : (($pencilbanner == 'std') ? 'banner__standard' : (($pencilbanner == 'lim') ? 'banner__limited' : 'banner__none' ))); ?>"></div>
```

Comment: To be honest, you're just making the code less readable and less maintainable by going down this route. Why not introduce a `$banner_css` variable further up in the code so you can have some whitespace with your if/else if conditions.

Comment: You can do it with nested ternaries, but I strongly suggest you don't do it. It just gets confusing with no actual benefit. Use the `if` statements to set a variable, then use that in the `echo`.

Comment: You're missing the `echo` statement in the version with the ternary.

Comment: I'd recommend this answer from linked question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/5235687/3783243. Specifically `It is recommended to avoid "stacking" ternary expressions.`

Comment: @miken32 You closed it as a duplicate of the same question he referenced.

Comment: `$class = match($pencilbanner) {'hol' => 'banner__holiday', 'std' => 'banner__standard', 'lim' => 'banner__limited', default => 'banner__none'};` somewhere else, and then `echo $class` inline seems much cleaner.

Comment: @Barmar technically it should probably be closed as a typo due to the missing echo. Really this coding style just shouldn't be used at all.

Comment: @miken32 I hadn't actually read enough of the ternary to be sure that he got that right, so I wasn't sure it was just the `echo` typo. But any closure is good enough, that's why I didn't reopen.

Comment: Ok. I'm not a PHP dev, but I'm trying to work with it. I guess I'm not going to have this inline ternary. I'm trying to add the conditions to a single variable, then echo that variable, but it's proving difficult.

Comment: You may find some joy with [switch](https://www.php.net/switch), or if you're on PHP 8, [match](https://www.php.net/match). Otherwise, have a reference array with `$ban_ref = ['hol' => 'banner__holiday', ...]` and simply `echo $ban_ref[$pencilbanner]`. Please remember, you don't need to stuff all your code on a single line, it's terribly unreadable.